# How to make my database information appear on my app

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, kotlin, jdbc

Hello I am trying to connect my MySQL (not SQLite) database to my app on android studio using kotlin but when I run my app there isn't anything appearing and I have a textview set up in my xml file. What can I do to help display my database information?

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.Statement

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  var strSelect: TextView? = null
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     strSelect = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView) as TextView
  }
}
object Test {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recreation?useSSL=false"
        val username = "root"
        val password = "xxxxx"
        var con: Connection? = null
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password)
            val stmt: Statement = con.createStatement()
            println("Connected to MySQL database")
            val strSelect =
                ("SELECT startTime, endTime, day FROM hoursOfOperations JOIN recreationCenterHours_of_Operations ON "
                        + "hoursOfOperations.dayCode = recreationCenterHours_of_Operations.dayCode where recID='KP002';")
            val rset: ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect)
            while (rset.next()) {   // Move the cursor to the next row, return false if no more row
                println(
                    rset.getString("startTime")
                        .toString() + " - " + rset.getString("endTime") + " " + rset.getString("day")
                )
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using Room for your database?

Comment: What do you mean?